# Is it possible to run NUnit tests from my code directly?

Tags: c#, testing, automation, nunit, playwright

I have a ton of tests across multiple test files and test fixtures, and I need them to run in a specific order (regardless of what test fixture or file they are in). Currently I have a list of MethodInfo objects which have the name and other attributes attached. Is there any way for me to iterate over a list of these objects and run the tests from code?

Context-
The tests are for a server-based web tool which means that the server needs to be reconfigured for some tests, ideally we don't want to have to constantly reconfigure the server as it takes a few minutes each time, so we have a set of predefined configurations (1-5). Each test is tagged with a config attribute, we essentially need tests to run in batches with other tests of the same config.

E.g.
Test 1 - Config 1
Test 2 - Config 2
Test 3 - Config 1

It would make no sense to swap configs twice and would be more ideal to run test 1 and 2 before test 3, however I can't seem to find a way to run my tests via MethodInfo or name.

Any advice would be appreciated!

I feel like I have searched every crevice of every forum post and can't find a good answer which doesn't involve installing more packages. ChatGPT has also been useless as it just keeps giving me answers that are completely wrong or use classes that just don't exist in the NUnit framework

Comment: NUnit describes itself as a unit-testing framework, but what you're describing sound like integration tests. Would it work for you to refactor away to a different test running framework, or even just write a custom console application that calls all your test methods in the desired order?

Comment: How exactly do you tag your tests? It should be possible to just run the tests that are tagged a certain way, so you could run all the tests tagged with config1 together, for instance. I have never tried this with NUnit though.